# update Value to - updated value in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have build a Cloud firestore database with 'TotalView' count feature to display in my flutter app.

I stream data from Firestore using below (example) link;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CollectionID').snapshots();
```

Same item can be viewed by multiple user at same time, each time user views and exits (not on access / opening views but data updates when user stops viewing or move on to next) that item - I want to add (+1) the realtime (last updated value) - `viewCount` in my database

liveVideos.doc('docID').update({'viewsCount': viewCount + 1})

I am able to update this value with below example way;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CollectionID')
.doc('docID')
.update({'viewCount' : 'initiallyFetchedViewCount' + 1})
```

above code adds (+1) to the `viewCount` that was initially fetched. But in case if the `viewCount`
in server is already updated (if the value is already increased) then I want to add (+1) to that increased value and not the one that was initially fetched.

example stat;
**data when initially fetched**

```
viewCount : 15
```

**data by the time user closed the view**

```
viewCount : 33
```

here, i want server to add (+1) to updated value (`+1` to `33` but not to `15`).

I couldn't explain it better or short way, sorry for lengthy explanation.
Looking for any clue or way around to have this achieved. Appreciate any piece of help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change it from the backend. If you use a `increment` Field it will automaticaly increment the value to the latest highest number on the backend:

```
DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update("population", FieldValue.increment(50));
```

More on that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

Another solution would be to use a transaction:

```
// Create a reference to the document the transaction will use
DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(documentId);

return FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  // Get the document
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    throw Exception("User does not exist!");
  }

  // Update the follower count based on the current count
  // Note: this could be done without a transaction
  // by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()

  int newFollowerCount = snapshot.data()['followers'] + 1;

  // Perform an update on the document
  transaction.update(documentReference, {'followers': newFollowerCount});

  // Return the new count
  return newFollowerCount;
})
.then((value) => print("Follower count updated to $value"))
.catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user followers: $error"));
```

More on that [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#transactions).

It is importand to know that for both of those you would need to have internet a working internet connection. Usualy firestore would also work without it.

Comment: `FieldValue.increment(1)` solved my issue.  @TarikHuber Thank you for the prompt response (plus) perfect Solution. You are awesome !